# Format Json, remove duplicates and count elements in javascript

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json

I'm a little lost, I have a dataset in json format with timestamps and ids like this:

```
[{
  "date":"2016-11-18 19:20:42","id_pa":"7"
},{
  "date":"2016-11-18 19:04:55","id_pa":"5"
},{
  "date":"2016-11-19 20:53:42","id_pa":"7"
},{
  "date":"2016-11-19 20:53:43","id_pa":"7"
},{
  "date":"2016-11-19 20:53:43","id_pa":"7"
},{
  "date":"2016-11-20 20:49:42","id_pa":"7"
},{
  "date":"2016-11-20 20:50:45","id_pa":"7"
},{
  "date":"2016-11-20 20:50:46","id_pa":"7"
}]
```

And I want to build a json that displays the date and the number of IDs each day. The new Json would be like this:

```
[{
  "date":"18-11-2016","num_pa":"2"
},{
  "date":"19-11-2016","num_pa":"1"
},{
  "date":"20-11-2016","num_pa":"1"
}]
```

I figured I had to do a **.map** to format the date so it shows dd-mm-yyyy, then a **.filter** to remove duplicates and finally a **.reduce** to count the diferent ids for every date. So far I've done only the .map procedure but I'm not sure how to do the next steps and either my solution is the best solution or not.

This is a piece of my code:

```
SwapSvc
    .getUsage (vm.id_fi)
    .then((data)=>{
        //console.log(`lreceived data: `+ JSON.stringify(data) );
        vm.fdata = data.map((elem) => {
        //console.log(`date: ${elem.date}`);
        //console.log(`id_pa: ${elem.id_pa}`);
        var d = new Date (elem.date);
        return{
            date:d.getDate()+'-'+d.getMonth()+'-'+d.getFullYear()/*elem.date*/,
            id_pa:elem.id_pa
        }})
        var temp = [];
        vm.filteredData = vm.fdata.filter((elem, index) => {
            if(temp.indexOf(elem.date)<0){
                temp.push(elem);
                return true;
                }
            else return false;
        });
        console.log(`data after parsing and ordering: `+ JSON.stringify(vm.filteredData) ); 
        return data;
    })
    .catch((err)=>{
        //error
        console.log(`error, no response`);
        throw err;
    });
```

PS: I'm using angular 1.6 with ES6.
Thanks in advance
BRJ

Comment: Are you trying to return the modified data from the function or log it to the console?

Comment: First of all I want to log it to the console for testing but after that I want to display the data in a graph.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use a hash table for the date and collect all `id_pa` for later count.

```js
var data = [{ date: "2016-11-18 19:20:42", id_pa: "7" }, { date: "2016-11-18 19:04:55", id_pa: "5" }, { date: "2016-11-19 20:53:42", id_pa: "7" }, { date: "2016-11-19 20:53:43", id_pa: "7" }, { date: "2016-11-19 20:53:43", id_pa: "7" }, { date: "2016-11-20 20:49:42", id_pa: "7" }, { date: "2016-11-20 20:50:45", id_pa: "7" }, { date: "2016-11-20 20:50:46", id_pa: "7" }],
    hash = Object.create(null),
    result;

data.forEach(function (a) {
    var date = a.date.slice(0, 10);
    hash[date] = hash[date] || Object.create(null);
    hash[date][a.id_pa] = true;
});
result = Object.keys(hash).map(date => ({ date, num_pa: Object.keys(hash[date]).length }));

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: Thanks it works very well, I'll consider this solution in the future.

Answer (score 0):

You can just chain `reduce` onto your `map` call and use the ES6 `findIndex` method to see if the object currently exists within the array being created by the `reduce` function.

```
SwapSvc
    .getUsage (vm.id_fi)
    .then((data)=>{
        //console.log(`lreceived data: `+ JSON.stringify(data) );
        vm.fdata = data.map((elem) => {
        //console.log(`date: ${elem.date}`);
        //console.log(`id_pa: ${elem.id_pa}`);
        var d = new Date (elem.date);
        return{
            date:d.getDate()+'-'+d.getMonth()+'-'+d.getFullYear()/*elem.date*/,
            id_pa:elem.id_pa
        }}).reduce((p, c, i) => {
            var index = p.findIndex(x => x.date === c.date);
            if (index !== -1) p[index].num_pa++;
            else p.push({"date": c.date, "num_pa": 1})
            return p;
        }, [])

        console.log(`data after parsing and ordering: `+ JSON.stringify(vm.fData) ); 
        return data;
    })
```

Comment: Thanks it works like a charm, this is exactly was I was looking for!